# Find $f,g$ for a counterexample of multivariable limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Are there any $f,g : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0, \lim_{y \rightarrow 0}g(y) = 0$ but $$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \dfrac{\log(1+f(x)g(y))}{g(y)} \neq 0 \quad ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{log(1+x)}{x}=1$, so $|log(1+x)|\leq \frac{3}{2}|x|$, when $|x|<\delta$.

$|\dfrac{\log(1+f(x)g(y))}{g(y)}|=\frac{3}{2}|\dfrac{f(x)g(y)}{g(y)}|=\frac{3}{2}|f(x)|\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

So I don't think there exist such $f,g$.